# Curl output json list

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

I have a curl commando and get this back

Data:

```
import os

cmd = "curl 'https://localhost/api?status=RUNNING'"
data = os.system(cmd)
print(str(data))
```

Output:

```
root@test /home/local/ # python3 main.py
[
  "testdir1",
  "testdir2",
  "testdir3"
]0
root@test /home/local/ #
```

How can I put `testdir1`, `testdir2`, and `testdir3` in a variable?

With this code, I get exactly the same output:

```
cmd = "curl 'https://localhost/api?status=RUNNING'"
data = os.system(cmd)
for v in str(data):
  print(v)
```

I also don't know where the 0 comes from at the end.

Comment: The 0 is the return code of the curl subprocess. Don't use os.system, just use urllib or requests directly.

Comment: can you tell me how the script looks like with urlib pls?

Comment: Nope.  It's not difficult.  Read the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html   try it yourself, and come back if you have any specific questions or problems.

Answer (score 0):

os.system is running a command, which itself can write to stdout.
Additionally, you execute print ('0') after that.

```
import os
rc = os.system('echo hello')
print('the command returned:', rc)
```

> hello
> the command returned: 0

You can find more information about the value returned by os.system here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system